# Angular RouteProvider - resolve not passing object to controller

Tags: angularjs

Take a look at the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uEbEdNifuBReENxzhb6H?p=preview

The expected behaviour for the routeProvider resolve (to my understanding) is for the resolved object to be injected into the controller. However Angularjs throws an "Unknown provider" error.

I have seen suggestions to inject the original service, but that will result in a deferred object, which renders the routeProvider resolve rather useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the controller with the root provider - not in the template (or the controller will be used regardless of the path, which may result in the dependencies not resolving):

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{controller:'TestCtrl', ...
```

I've updated your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mSb58e8cGDNYU27xSizk?p=preview

Comment: `functions returning the injected value (and if the return value is a promise angular will wait until it is resolved before the controller is initialized):` no, they can be simple aliases

Comment: Right - I'm sorry - somehow I missed the 'testService', I've updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks, it does work but defining the controller in the view shouldn't break my example. Should it?

Comment: It fails because angular calls the controller twice, and the second time the dependency injection fails: http://plnkr.co/edit/7mjVMljCq4iWuKcdEMKz?p=preview

Comment: The plnkr doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: Not sure which one you're referring to, all of my plnkr's exist. Might have been a temporary problem with plnkr.co - they've had some performance issues lately