# Can an Angular JS template contain a controller?

Tags: angularjs

Here's my route...

```js
angular.module('ng').
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/User_View', { templateUrl: '/rest/tbot/run/User_View' });
    });
```

In the template it has the following...

```html
<div ng-controller="TMUser">
```

TMUser is defined in the template in a script block. But the code in the controller doesn't appear to run. Why is this?

Comment: Unless you're doing something a little unusual, you are missing ".html" in your templateUrl?

Comment: Url rewrite on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller shouldn't be defined in the template file. I don't think Angular can know about it and load it that way. Define it in a code file that will be executed before the route change happens.

You can also specify the controller in the `routeProvider` configuration object, like:

```js
when('/User_View', { templateUrl: '/rest/tbot/run/User_View', controller:'TMUser' });
```

[This fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSb58e8cGDNYU27xSizk?p=preview) demonstrates a very simple example ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466650/angular-routeprovider-resolve-not-passing-object-to-controller))

Comment: Not very modularised then. What if I've got a single page app that's made up of a hundred pages... does that mean I need to load a hundred pages of script in the host page?

Comment: You could use something like RequireJS to load your modules. But unless you have some unique and long controller code for each of those hundreds of pages (which is highly unlikely) minimizing and optimizing with Google Closure will get you a long way

Comment: This is a sample app which demonstrates the concept: https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs-optimisation

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct.
But i achived the same thing using ng-include and ng-hide, what exactly ng-view and routing does.

I have created a partial page without controller and included that in parent page and made that partial page hidden after a button click i am just displaying the page.

Routing has there on benifit. you can pass the paramter and change the view accordingly ang browser history.

here is my page conatins below code inside a child controller.

```html
<span ng-include="'/PartialPages/ChangeDetails.htm'"></span>
```

which refers my parital page

```html
 <div id="ChangeInfo" ng-show="datashow">
      <table width="100%">
       <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>File Name</th>
          <th>File Create Date</th>
          <th>File Modified Date</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="file in FilesDetails" ng-class="{TableStrip : ($index % 2)}">
         <td>{{file.FileName}}</td>
         <td>{{file.CreateDate}}</td>
         <td>{{file.ModifiedDate}}</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr />
    </div>
```

and the controller code

```js
var deploymentVerifierModule = angular.module("DeploymentVerifierApp", ['DeploymentServiceModule']);

deploymentVerifierModule.controller("DeploymentVerifierCntrl", function ($scope, DeploymentService) {
    $scope.datashow = false;
    $scope.PleaseWait = false;
    $scope.VerifyChange = function () {
        //Get the Change ticket number from textbox
        $scope.PleaseWait = true;
        var changeticketnum = document.getElementById("ChangeNumber").value;
        DeploymentService.GetChangeDetails(changeticketnum).then(function (data) {
            $scope.FilesDetails = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.PleaseWait = false;
            $scope.datashow = true;

        }, function (error) { });
    };
});
```

still i did not get some of your point why do you want controller to be in template. and templateurl property contains the extenstion of page also.

Comment: I want the controller in the template so that the javascript is only loaded when its needed. templateurl doesn't contain the extension if the page doesn't have an extension. ;)