# Why is my directive no longer showing up when placed inside an HTML template that is inserted via $http?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that works when placed inside my "shell" html template. I also have various template "partials" that are inserted into the shell template via `$http`. However, when I place my directive inside any of the partial templates that `$http` grabs, then the directive no longer works. Why? Is there something about scope that I'm missing?

AngularJS:

```
.directive( 'button', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
scope: true,
templateUrl: 'button.html',
link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
  scope.button_title = attrs.button;
} 
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div button="My Button"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle, plunker, or more information (for example, the contents of `button.html`?

Comment: The code is basically just ``<button type="button">My Button</button>`` I can get it to work when the directive is placed inside the main controller for my app (``appCtrl``). But, when I place the directive inside of a partial template (that has its own controller) it no longer works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an Angular JS template container a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514103/can-an-angular-js-template-container-a-controller)

Comment: no, this is not a duplicate.